# Replacing data from column1 to another column 2 in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace the values from Column1 to Column2 And also want to export the same in to_csv. Please help me to get this correct

[image]

Comment: Do you think replace missing values? What is expected output?

Comment: Is the figure represent your desired output?

Comment: Hi Jezrael : there is value column1 {1,2,3,None,5} want replace the data of column2{NA,2,3,NA,5} respectively , and export to_csv file

Comment: Yes @AtanuCSE, exactly replaced as column2